# what if length attribute is not defined in hibernate mapping file, what will be the default value for a column then?

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, alter-table

What will happen if i do not define length attribute in my hibernate mapping hbm.xml file?

what is the default length value it will take for that column?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with "one shot"? A single SQL statement? A single PL/SQL block? A single transaction?

Comment: yes, to all your question

Comment: Oracle does not support transactional DDL, so that part is impossible.

Comment: So i have to run alter command 100 times ?

Comment: Yes, either manually in SQL, or with a loop in PL/SQL

Comment: could you please give me how to run that through loop for many tables.

Comment: Use a [Cursor FOR Loop](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/cursor_for_loop_statement.htm) to step through the set of tables you want to alter, and [`execute immediate`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/executeimmediate_statement.htm) to make the changes. Bonus points for making it re-runnable e.g. for use in an automated deployment.

Comment: feel free to edit the question on how to do this specifically in SQL Developer, but i would suggest adding detail on exactly what you're wanting to change for the 100 tables

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged SQL Developer...

[You can grab this XML extension from our GitHub repo](https://github.com/oracle/oracle-db-examples/blob/master/sqldeveloper/extension/xml/individual/README.md). In particular, the 'MultiSelectObjectExample'

Once this is added, you can multi-select a ton of tables in the connection tree, right click, and generate your code to run.

[image]

Let's say you wan to add a column called STACKOVERFLOW, a VARCHAR2(4000), to a bunch of tables.

Select the tables, do the right click.

Then in the pop-up dialog:

[image]

Copy that block of text to a SQL Worksheet.

Run it.

[image]

See the button i have in the red box? If you click that, it'll copy the output to a new sql worksheet so you can run it.

This is a lot of steps, but if you want GUI help for dynamically doing something to a lot of objects, it could be very useful.

You could of course alter the code to add that text to a local variable and use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE, but then it would be very easy to mess up 100 tables in one go. I like the DBMS_OUTPUT way as it forces me to look at the code before I execute it.

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the list of tables and execute alter scripts you Need with execute immediate

In this example I rename all tables created under my user

```
begin

  for rec in (select * from user_tables)
    execute immediate 'ALTER TABLE '|| rec.table_name|| ' RENAME TO DUP_'|| rec.table_name;
  end Loop;

end;
/
```

You can then dynamically generate the alter command that you need from the data dictionary